# matplotlib 3D Surface Plot - smooth

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have my data, and I want to create a smooth plot, however after running the code, it turns out too rough. Is there a way to smooth out the plot?

my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
# ax.view_init(azim=120, elev=30)

X = visualdf.lat
Y = visualdf.lan 
Z = visualdf.students
xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),(len(Z)/3))
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),(len(Z)/3))
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='nearest')

xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

ls = LightSource(270,45)
rgb = ls.shade(zi, cmap=cm.gist_earth , vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi, rstride=1, cstride=1, antialiased=True, shade=False, facecolors=rgb, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

ax.set_title('Lat, Lan & No of Students')
ax.set_xlabel('Latitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Longitude')
ax.set_zlabel('No of Students')
ax.set_zlim3d(0,3000)
```

3D plot:

[image]

Desired 3D plot, something like below:
Taken from - https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/custom_shaded_3d_surface.html
[image]

Comment: You can resample the data (effectively take a moving spatial or nearest-neighbor average) but this will create artificial smoothing - some of the information will be lost. Would that be acceptable? Or do you need to perfectly preserve the data?

Comment: Ideally preserving the data

Comment: How do you expect to preserve the data if you're smoothing the plot? "Smoothing" means losing the resolution of your data as you try to find a (simplistic) function to fit your complex data